# Bot Framework Prompt Dialog with Image

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm working with the Bot Framework and I want to display list of choices which have image attached by using method **PromptDialog.Choice** in order to take advantage of the **ResumeAfterChoose** method to control my business logic. However, I've only seen the Attachment Dialog which has written in [EchoBot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/EchoBot/EchoAttachmentDialog.cs) and it only creates list of messages that make me difficult to handle my business logic after client choose one of the list. Please show me the way to implement that. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, but using node instead of c# :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, you can't do that. There are a few ways to achieve that though.

First of all, you are saying that using attachments won't work for you because you won't be able to handle your business logic. That's partially true; but not for the reason you are mentioning.

You could put together a list of `HeroCards` with buttons and use the carousel layout for the attachments (see the [RichCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards) and the [CarouselCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-CarouselCards) samples). Then, you can just perform a `context.Wait` to a different method (similar to the `ResumeAfterChoose` method in the `PromptDialog`) and handle the logic there. That method will get the value of the button clicked and then you can perform your business logic. Now... the caveat with that is that if the user writes anything not aligned to the options you still will hit this method.

Guess what? What I just described is extremely similar to what the `PromptDialog.Choice` does behind the scenes... with the only difference that it adds a Retry logic to handle the caveat I mentioned and that the layout used is a list one because it just render a single `HeroCard` with multiple buttons (the options)

The way I would go in this case, is trying to put together a custom [PromptStyler](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L178), override the `Apply<T>` method and add your logic to render the Choice options in the way you want based on the [PromptStyle](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L49) used.

By default the [PromptDialog.Choice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L346) uses PromptStyle.Auto, that at the end of the game (in the PromptStyler) [converts the options into a HeroCard with multiple buttons](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L247). You could easily change that logic to create multiple cards and also uses images for them.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with my project! Always you support me when I asked about the Bot Framework. I'll try to implement like your suggestion. Many thanks!