# Prompt dialog choice with images - node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, botframework

I want the user to be prompted with different options, but instead of text, I want them to be pictures, so the user would be able to click the image he/she wants.

I'm working with Microsoft bot framework in node.js.

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848591/bot-framework-prompt-dialog-with-image) but with node instead of C#.

I have also checked [prompts documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/prompts/#promptschoice) but it look as if it weren't possible out of the box.

My bot is running on FaceBook, Perhaps it's not so important.

Comment: Have you considered https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-CarouselCards ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is not a feature of the existing prompt system in BotBuilder SDK as of 5/8/17, but you are welcome to contribute this feature via a pull request to [Microsoft/BotBuilder](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder).

Answer (score 0):

Please check out AdaptiveCards: http://adaptivecards.io/

Here is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards

Here is the npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adaptivecards

Adaptive Cards enable prompting users with images they can click on (just what you're looking for).