# Formatting PromptDialog.Choice In Our Own Way

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am using `PromptDialog.Choice` to show details of the Doctor schedule. This is the output what I get now.

[image: Bot Emulator Image]

I want to format this in this manner

Hospital Name        Available Day           Sessions             Appointment No

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go here is a combination of creating your own PromptStyler as I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42857663/90081) and using [AdaptiveCards](http://adaptivecards.io) to create a nice tabular view to show your options and probably adding a button.